# How to install template or theme in laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I need to install an **admin panel theme** in laravel. Please share any ideas.

Comment: Can you get upgraded to laravel 5.x?  You can install multiple themes with https://github.com/caffeinated/themes/

Answer (score 0):

Look like there is a project for it.

-> https://github.com/harryxu/laravel-theme

and see "Usage". (only for themes, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

There are packages such as `"cartalyst/themes": "3.0.*"`

You can insall them by including this in your `composer.json`

```
"cartalyst/themes": "3.0.*"
```

and do

```
composer update
```

Here is the [link](https://cartalyst.com/manual/themes/3.0) about that.

Also you shall use [this](https://github.com/teepluss/laravel-theme) and many such are available over github and other resources.

But i would recommend you to put the css and js files in your assets folder and simply use the html in your blades

**Recommendation :** Still why Laravel `4.2`, why not `5.1`

Answer (score 0):

https://cartalyst.com/manual/themes/3.0#installation

install composer before. Site to composer is too obvious to put it here